# Strange illumination in the roughness of the texture

Tags: texturing, shaders, roughness

I'm trying to import this texture:
https://www.poliigon.com/texture/metal-spotty-discoloration-001/3225

From here you can see how I did it and the result
[image]

To download the texture images and the .blend file I shared everything here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1d0PDnWH9VRH86OyYz8pmwltxfbkLDh0z?usp=sharing

What am I doing wrong? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your point light is extremely bright, *50,000* watts is the strength. Set it to something low, like around 1000-3000 if you want a *really* bright scene but still retain the colour:[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the result should be shinier, more metallic, like this: https://www.poliigon.com/texture/metal-spotty-discoloration-001/3225
instead it looks dull

Comment: @IacopoGuarneri that depends on your lighting, and you can adjust the roughness from the value you have gotten on the group node.